# Extracting JSON Response using Bean Shell Postprocessor

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to extract the value of one variable of a JSON array using Beanshell postprocessor but I am not getting any response in log

My JSON somewhat looks like:

```js
"store":
:   [
:   :   {
:   :   :   "storeId":12345,
:   :   :   "storeName":"ABC",
:   :   :   "storeAddress":"DEFGHIJKL",
:   :   :   "storeMinOrderAmount":100,
:   :   :   "mobile":"+911234567890",
:   :   :   "mobileSecondary":null,
:   :   :   "city":"Somewhere",
:   :   :   "pincode":123456,
:   :   :   "country":"India",
:   :   :   "email":"ptrm@company.com",
:   :   :   "pickup":true,
:   :   :   "delivery":false,
:   :   :   "storeSplashPath":null,
:   :   :   "storeSplashType":null,
:   :   :   "distance":"0.10"
:   :   },
```

And my Beanshell Post Processor is:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

print("*******************");

//Get Store total count
int totalStoreNumber = StringUtils.countMatches(new String(data), "storeId");
print("Total Number of Stores are: " + totalStoreNumber);

if (totalStoreNumber > 0) {
 //Check for Fulfilment type is "Pickup"
String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JsonObject store = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString);
JsonArray store = store.get("store").asArray();
String pickup = store.get(1).asObject().get("pickup").asString();
vars.put("fulfilmentType_BSH", pickup);
print("Is Pickup allowed: " + pickup);
}
else {
 print("No Stores Nearby");
}
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. I had read the related queries but couldn't get this right.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 9):

First of all, why don't you use [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) for it? You can get absolutely the same using single simple [JSON Path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression like:

```
$.store[0].pickup
```

---

If for any reason you still need to do it in Beanshell I have some ideas:

1. This is definitely the error. You cannot declare 2 variables with the same name in Beanshell script

   ```
   JsonObject store = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString);
   JsonArray store = store.get("store").asArray(); 
   //        ^^^^^  ka-boom!
   ```
2. Possible problem. [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) if there will be only 1 store in the response. In Beanshell collections are zero-based, 1st element will have index of 0.

   ```
   String pickup = store.get(1).asObject().get("pickup").asString();
   //                        ^ ka-boom!
   ```
3. Another possible problem could be regarding your imports, just in case

   ```
   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONObject;
   import com.eclipsesource.json.*;
   ```

   Have you added the relevant jars to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and have you restarted JMeter after this? Are you sure you're using methods correctly?

Here is your code re-implemented using [json-smart](http://netplex.github.io/json-smart/) which comes with JMeter 3.0 (you don't need any other jars)

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

//Get Store total count
int totalStoreNumber = StringUtils.countMatches(new String(data), "storeId");
log.info("Total Number of Stores are: " + totalStoreNumber);

if (totalStoreNumber > 0) {
    //Check for Fulfilment type is "Pickup"
    String jsonString = new String(data);
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(JSONParser.MODE_JSON_SIMPLE);
    JSONObject store = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data);
    JSONArray storeArray = (JSONArray) store.get("store");
    String pickup = ((JSONObject) storeArray.get(0)).getAsString("pickup");
    vars.put("fulfilmentType_BSH", pickup);
    log.info("Is Pickup allowed: " + pickup);
} else {
    log.info("No Stores Nearby");
}
```

And the evidence of its work

[image: Beanshell JSON demo]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell scripting in your JMeter tests