# Jmeter - How to validate portions of response json

Tags: json, jmeter

I have the following json:

```
{
"content":
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "userId":2,
        "storeId":8,
        "userFirstName":"Max",
        "userLastName":"Mustermann",
       "city":"Berlin",
        "spendQuantity":100,

        "paymentStatus":"UNPAID",
        "userBalanceStatus":null,
        "rateObject":
        {
            "identifier":23,
            "id":"432",
            "rate":"1.9345345",
            "symbol":"USD",
            "rank":2,

        }
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "userId":2,
        "storeId":3,
        "userFirstName":"Newman",
        "userLastName":"Mustermann",
       "city":"Berlin",
        "spendQuantity":1000,

        "paymentStatus":"UNPAID",
        "userBalanceStatus":null,
        "rateObject":
        {
            "identifier":3,
            "id":"234",
              "rate":"1.922222245345",
            "symbol":"USD",
            "rank":2,

        }
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "userId":2,
        "storeId":3,
        "userFirstName":"Newman",
        "userLastName":"Mustermann",
       "city":"Munich",
        "spendQuantity":3000,

        "paymentStatus":"UNPAID",
        "userBalanceStatus":null,
        "rateObject":
        {
            "identifier":2332,
            "id":"234",
               "rate":"3.234234",
            "symbol":"USD",
            "rank":2,

        }
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "userId":2,
        "storeId":3,
        "userFirstName":"Newman",
        "userLastName":"Mustermann",
       "city":"Essen",
        "spendQuantity":4000,

        "paymentStatus":"UNPAID",
        "userBalanceStatus":null,
        "rateObject":
        {
            "identifier":234,
            "id":"234",
               "rate":"333.234234",
            "symbol":"USD",
            "rank":2,

        }
    }
```

}

But I need to verify it partially - Only the fields in the nested jsons where city is Berlin or Essen, but without the rateObject (I don't need to verify this part). With other words I need to verify nested jsons with ids- 1,2,4 - all fields, without the information in rateObject.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer and Suggestion:

1. We can apply the filter condition in the JSON Query to fetch the matched details.

For Example: To get the id of the mentioned city,

**JSON Query:**

```
$.content[?(@.city=="Berlin" || @.city=="Essen")].id
```

**Output:**

```
[
    1,
    2,
    4
]
```

Similarly, you can assert all the required fields using the filter JSON Query. 
JMeter JSON Extractor will provide only one value at a time.So, you can either add some logic to verify all the occurrences or multiple verification can be added by specifying the id index ( $.content[?(@.city=="Berlin" || @.city=="Essen")].id[0] --> It gives the first occurrence Id )

2. If you want to validate multiple fields,then you can write the customized script in Bean Shell Post Processor.(Refer the below link and you will get some idea)

[Extracting JSON Response using Bean Shell Postprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251042/extracting-json-response-using-bean-shell-postprocessor)

If you are using the Bean Shell Post Processor, then required java jar files should be placed in JMeter ClassPath( Folder: apache-jmeter-4.0\lib\ext)